# Image Saved from Page Scrape Disappearing on Hover

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cdn

I have an program that takes a user input URL, scrapes the page for images, and saves those images to my CDN.  This normally works fine, but when trying using it on the [this URL](http://www.anntaylor.com/ann/product/product:305510/AT-PROMO-49.50-STYLES/Paisley-Print-Carnegie-Cropped-Pants/305510?skuId=13552404&catid=cat1490008&defaultColor=3140&productPageType=fullPriceProducts&productType=relatedProduct) it saves the image - but some strange behavior is exhibited when I use that image referencing my CDN link.  Notably, the height and width are set to 0 and there are other styles applied.  When I inspect the image in the Chrome debugger, i get the below styles all in line:

```
element.style {
-webkit-user-select: none;
display: none !important;
visibility: hidden !important;
opacity: 0 !important;
background-position: 488px 600px;
}
img[Attributes Style] {
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
}
```

I have no idea why this is happening but there are two links loaded along with the image and this only happens in chrome, so I don't know why Chrome has decided to do this but FF doesn't:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="chrome-extension://cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="chrome-extension://cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/page_context.js"></script>
```

[You can see the behavior here](http://e3da8dc1c3cfdf394995-184e01705dd318c162d0284c163588ca.r86.cf1.rackcdn.com/richmedia.channeladvisor.com052513011149657.jpg).  I have no idea why this is happening, I save the image to my CDN with ImageFormat.Jpeg, so I'm a bit confused and this works for other sites/images just fine.

I'd rather not write a bunch of javascript to offset these styles, so any pointers would be awesome!  Thanks!